# SQL Server cross database insert: The INSERT permission was denied

Tags: sql-server

We have 2 databases on a single SQL Server 2014 server.

A Windows service running as [NT Authority/System] is executing a stored procedure on database A, and this stored procedure tries to insert rows into a table on database B. 
This fails with

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'table_in_database_B', database 'database B', schema 'dbo'.
```

[NT Authority/System] is defined as server admin and dbo on both databases, and database chaining is on.
We even tried to `grant select on [table_in_database_B] to public`, but this did not help.

What can we be missing?

Comment: Running a service as SYSTEM and giving that account admin access is a **very bad idea**. It means that if anything goes wrong, the service can destroy anything on the server. Since you're using local accounts why not create a local account with access only to the thing it needs? **No** application account needs admin access to the database by the way

Comment: As for the problem itself, the account used doesn't have *INSERT* permissions on the target table. You should use GRANT INSERT, not GRANT SELECT. The privilege should be granted to the *account*, not `public`.

Comment: Does this sp have EXECUTE AS clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes, I know it's a bad idea. Currently that's what we need. Thanks for pointing that out though. As for the permission - I thought that a user defined as DBO would have insert permission on all tables... no?

Comment: @sepupic no, it does not have EXECUTE AS, but that might actually be a solution. I've never used it. I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: If your sp has EXECUTE AS clause you are sendboxed within your first database

Comment: @user884248 no you don't need it at all. It actually makes things *harder* to fix because you think you bypassed permision problems with this, when obviously you haven't. None of the things you tried is necessary

Comment: No, it is NOT a solution, it could be the cause why that account is not sysadmin anymore

Comment: What you should do is add to your proc select user, system_user code to find out under what account your application is logged effectively

Comment: @user884248 even worse, you can't even *test* your SQL now, because you can't login as SYSTEM to SSMS and test your query. Fix the account, then test the query using that service account.  Can you execute the query by itself? Can you execute it as part of your stored procedure?

Comment: @user884248 If you want to give a blanket privilege to the account, use `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`.

Comment: First he should find out under WHAT account he is logged in. It obviously NOT sysadmin, and it can be NOT LocalSystem

Comment: Quite a lively debate going on here... Thank you both! I understand I need to change [NT Authority\System], but right now I just want to understand what's going on here. Curiously, when I gave [NT Authority\System] full permissions to the table being inserted (select,delete,insert,update,take ownership,etc) that didn't help. But... When I added the [NT Authority\System] login to the SysAdmin server role, everything worked fine. This is NOT how I know SQL Server permissions to work... What can be the cause?

Comment: Try ```grant execute on [table_in_database_B] to public```

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms suggest the ownership chain is broken even though `DB_CHAINING` is on. The `dbo` schema is owned by the database owner so both databases must have the same owner in order to maintain an unbroken ownership chain for dbo-owned objects. The user needs to have access to both databases and `EXECUTE` permissions on the stored procedure. No other object permissions are required with an unbroken ownership chain.

This can be remediated by chaining the database owners to a common server-level principal:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DatabaseA TO DatabaseOwnerLogin;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DatabaseB TO DatabaseOwnerLogin;
```

Comment: If the login is sysadmin as OP says, it access any database without "db chaining on". The OP's problem is that this code IS NOT executed under sysadmin, so he should find out the right login, corresponding user, and grant permissions to right user

Comment: @sepupic, right, the original login is not `sysadmin` since `sysadmin` role members have full permissions in all databases and permissions are not checked. I was detailing how to make it work without sysadmin.